# What is the logical negation of this statement

Tags: logic

What is the logical negation of the following statement:

For every integer $n≥2$, there exist natural numbers $x,y$ and $z$ such that $$n(xy+xz+yz)=4xyz$$

My **solution**: There exist an integer $n≥2$ such that $$n(xy+xz+yz)≠4xyz$$ for all natural numbers $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: If I may ask, why did you accept the answer that says "everything you said is right" while in mine I pointed-out to a minor mistake?

Comment: @Scientifica: Since the case $n=2$ is true.

Comment: Indeed it is true for $n=2$ (for the 3-tuple $(2,2,1)$), however the statement you gave is **not** the negation of your solution, rather a statement **logically equivalent** to the negation of your solution in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: @Scientifica: Yes. Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. In a more general sense:

> For every $x$, $A$ happens

is negated by:

> There is an $x$ for which $A$ does not happen

Therefore:

> For every $x$, there is $y$ such that $P(x,y)$ is true

Is negated by:

> There is an $x$ such that $P(x,y)$ is false for every possible $y$

Answer (score 5):

Yup that's correct, with the exception that you should say "There exists an integer $n\ge 2$" instead of $n>2$.

**Edit:** You pointed out in comments that $n=2$ satisfies the given statement. Your solution however is still **not** the negation of the given statement, rather a statement **logically equivalent** to the given statement in $(\mathbb N,+,\times)$. Remember, statements are strings of symbols, and two different statements (different strings of symbols) might have the same "meaning" in a structure, but they're still different nevertheless.